# Reset wpf application fully

Tags: c#, wpf, reset

There is some way for reset `wpf` application  fully? I mean not application restart

```
Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Above code shutdowns current window and opens new.

I ask, if there is a way, for fully reset all happened events and set starting values for variables,  `XAML` objects and etc. without window closing?

Of course, this may make step by step for every variables and objects, but may be exists some short method?

Comment: A good short method would be to have the appropriate architecture implemented to reset each module to initial values. It could also be the lognest method if you haven't got any architecture for that set up in place.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no fast method. The best bet is to use an architecture that separates Model/state from View and then create a new instance of your model. MVVM is a good architecture for WPF and will do just fine.